# What is the difference between H(M) and H3(M, s, IDA)?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-function

What is the difference between **H(M)** and **H3(M, s, IDA)**?

I am aware of Hash function with a Message and a Key, but there are three parameters in:

**H3(M, s, IDA)**.

Here **M** is the message, **s** is the key, and **IDA** is the identity of user A.
I meant that how to implement secure hash **H3(M,s,IDA)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take the [(previous version of the) question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/25927/3) as: how to implement a secure hash function $H3$ with 3 arguments, from one hash function $H$ with 1 argument, all with argument(s) in $\{0,1\}^*$.

Note: For a concrete $H$ with the destination set $\mathbb Z_p^*$ thought in the question, we could use [SHA3-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) followed by a suitable function; for example, $x\to H(x)=g^{\operatorname{SHA3-512}(x)}$ where $g$ is a [generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28mathematics%29) of $\mathbb Z_p^*$. That $H$ is [collision-resistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) to $\min\big(512,\log_2\varphi(p)\big)/2$ bits (where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)); and first and second preimage resistant to $\min\big(512,\log_2\varphi(p)\big)$ bits. Further, it is secure in the [Random Oracle Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) for suitable choice of $p$.

The construction $H3(M,S,I)=H(\;M\;\|\;S\;\|\;I\;)$ where $\|$ stands for concatenation of bitstrings is such that usual security properties of $H$ (including collision-resistance and security in the Random Oracle Model) demonstrably apply to $H3$, *if at most one of* $M$, $S$, $I$ *is of variable size*.

Otherwise it is *not* secure in general: exhibiting a collision is trivial; for example, $H3(\text{01},\text{0101},\text{0101})=H3(\text{0101},\text{0101},\text{01})$. However, with the middle parameters $S$ random, secret, and non-malleable (as presumably in the question), there is no spectacularly practical attack.

A secure construction for variable-size inputs is $H3\big(M,S,I\big)=H\big(\;E(M)\;\|\;E(S)\;\|\;I\;\big)$, where $E$ is a [prefix-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) function on $\{0,1\}^*$ ; that is, such that
$$\forall X\in \{0,1\}^*,\forall Y\in \{0,1\}^*,\forall Z\in \{0,1\}^*,E(X)=E(Y)\|Z\implies X=Y$$
Examples of suitable prefix-free constructions for $E(X)$:

- prefix each bit in $X$ with a $\text{0}$ bit, then append a final $\text{1}$.
- prefix $X$ of length $b$ bits with $b+1$ encoded in big-endian binary (thus with $\lceil\log_2(b+1)\rceil$ bits starting with a $\text{1}$ bit), then prefix that with $\lceil\log_2(b+1)\rceil-1$ bits at $\text{0}$.
- the encoding of [bitstrings in ASN.1 DER](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.6.6585&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=14) then re-encoded into a bitstring (e.g. using big-endian conventions for internal consistency).

Comment: is it means that H3(M,S,I) is the concatenation of M,S and I?

Comment: @Nubila: No, " _the concatenation of M,S and I_ " is not a secure hash. $\;$ $H3(M,S,I)$ _could_ be the _hash of_ the concatenation of $M$, $S$, and $I$, with the security issue discussed in the question; and should rather be the hash of the concatenation of $e(M)$, $e(S)$, and $I$.

Comment: Then how we calculate e(M)

Comment: @Nubila: I gave three examples of suitable functions $E$ (sorry I changed notation from $e$ to $E$). If this is for an actual implementation: If any two of $M$, $S$, $I$ are of fixed size, then $H3(M,S,I)=H(\;M\;\|\;S\;\|\;I\;)$ is just fine. Or perhaps $M$ and $S$ are restricted to bytestrings (not bitstrings) and of known maximum length; in which case $E(M)$ can simply be $M$ prefixed with the length of $M$ over a fixed number of bytes suitable for expressing the maximum length.

Comment: Ok...I have to implement it.Can we use SHA1 for this.

Comment: @Nubila: $H3(M,S,I)=\operatorname{SHA1}(\;M\;\|\;S\;\|\;I\;)$ with _all_ parameters of fixed length will be fine for all but a very powerful adversary: the best known attacks require work of $2^{63\pm9}$ hashes, and so far have not been performed publicly. Same with a single parameter of variable length if you do no not care for the length-extension attack (which breaks security in the ROM, mentioned in [version 1 of the question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/25927/1)). For output in $\mathbb Z_p$ (as originally asked), see note in answer, and change 512 to 160 for SHA1.

Comment: :Ok..What is the difference b/w   _**H3(M,S,I)**_  and  _**H1(I,S)**_. In my algorithm first initialize  H1 and H3 as  **H1 :{0, 1}*×Zp* → Zq***an
 d **H3 :{0, 1}* → Zq***.